# Python get script runtime in raunded minutes

Tags: python

I like to get the run time of the script in rounded minutes.

I put this at the start

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
```

And this at the end

```
print ("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
```

so I get output value in seconds like 246.60637378692627 seconds

I like to get instead 4,11 minutes

Comment: Use the built-in `round` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just divide your seconds by 60 and then use the `round` function:

```
time_taken = round((time.time() - start_time)/60.0, 2)

print ("My program took", time_taken, "to run")
```